# Mysql doesn't execute select statement in the desired order

Tags: php, mysql

I have this array:

```
$keys = Array(79, 68, 80, 78, 71, 69, 77, 82, 83, 70, 76, 74, 75)
```

I then make a query in my database using this array:

```
$dbh = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', array_map('intval', $keys)) . ")"); 

$stmt->execute();
```

But echoing out the result, like...

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    echo $row['id'] . '<br />';
}
```

...gives me:

```
69
70
71
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
```

That is, the result is sorted in ascending order. But I need the results to be sorted like the original array $keys (it represents a top list). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `IN` does not sort your results. It only selects records matching your query. If you want the results to be in order you need to add an `ORDER BY FIELD()` clause to your query.

```
$keyString = implode(',', array_map('intval', $keys));
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE id IN (" . $keyString  . ")
    ORDER BY FIELD(id, " . $keyString . ")");
```

Comment: He's asking for them not to be ordered, to stay in the original array's order.

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe Exactly, using order by field will do that.

Comment: OH, I misunderstood your original answer, I also didn't know about FIELD(), +1

Answer (score 1):

You have to define custom ordering for your query

```
 $orderstr="ORDER BY CASE id ";
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($keys);$i++)
    {$orderstr.="WHEN ".$keys[$i]. "Then".$i. "\n";}
    $orederstr.="END";
```

then you can use `$orderstr` in your query to order